# I can not get rails server to run on cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, undefined

When I run rails server this is the issue that I get:  rails server -b $IP -p $PORT

=> Booting WEBrick

=> Rails 4.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080

=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options

=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Exiting

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:142:in `log_to_stdout': undefined method`formatter' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I made adjustments to the config.ru file however that did not work so I changed it back. How do i fix this problem?

Comment: What does your `config.ru` look like?

Comment: require ::File.expand_path('../config/environments',  __FILE__)

run Rails.application

Comment: And have you edited `config.logger` anywhere in the Rails config files (`config/application.rb` for example)? Your error indicates a missing logger instance.

Comment: No I have not. How do I add that in there?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it, it should be set up automatically by default. Is this a bare bones Rails app or did you add or edit something? Please post your `Gemfile` too in the question.